# django - docfile adding %0D to url?

Tags: django

I have a weird issue where the `docfile.url` of a file on our server is adding a `%0D` (carriage return) to the end of the url. This is only happening to files that I mannually linked. What I mean is, there were about 1,000 files in a directory and I created a CSV file which had the `id` and `filename` of each file, and added them to the `mysql` database with some code. All files uploaded normally through my django app's interface link normally - clicking their link opens the file properly.

Here's a sample of the CSV file:

```
792,asbuilts/C0010.pdf
793,asbuilts/C0011.pdf
794,asbuilts/C0012.pdf
795,asbuilts/C0013.pdf
796,asbuilts/C0014.pdf
797,asbuilts/C0015.pdf
798,asbuilts/C0016.pdf
799,asbuilts/C0017.pdf
```

I have all these asbuilt files in the directory `static_media/asbuilts/`. In mysql I ran this command:

```
load data local infile '/srv/www/cpm/CPM_CSV_Files/comm_asbuilts.csv' into table systems_asbuilt fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (id, docFile);
```

A sample output of `select * from systems_asbuilt` is like this:

```
 |846 | asbuilts/C0057.pdf
 |847 | asbuilts/C0059.pdf
 |848 | asbuilts/C0060.pdf
 |849 | asbuilts/C0061.pdf
 |850 | asbuilts/C0062.pdf
 |851 | asbuilts/C0063.pdf
 |852 | asbuilts/C0064.pdf
```

Everything looks good right?

But when I look at the link created it looks like this:

```
`www.ourdomain.com/static_media/asbuilts/R0546.pdf%0D'
```

If I manually delete the `%0D` from the link, the file opens as expected. Any idea why there's the extra `%0D` on there? Where is it coming from?

Thanks

Comment: What's your operating system? Windows uses `CR LF` (`0D 0A`) for line endings; Linux and Mac OS X use `LF` (`0A`).

Comment: The site is running on Ubuntu Linux Server. I am following the links on a Mac - but I don't think the client side is the issue, I would assume its the server side.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that this:

`lines terminated by '\n'`

Should be

`lines terminated by '\r\n'`

Your result "looks" right because of the client you are using to browse it, but when the record is retrieved, it still has the `\r` appended to it.

So you can strip it before you load it in the database, or `.strip()` before you generate the link.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember the `\r\n` issue cropping up on me before somewhere else. I'll have to use the `.strip()` on the link since (if I understand correctly) it won't be a problem for those links that do not have a `\r` on the end. Thanks for the tip.